# How to nest yaml variable expressions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to nest yaml variable expressions in a Azure Devops Pipeline as one step uses the project name separated by spaces and another uses periods ie 'My Project' vs 'My.Project'.

This is what I have currently but the echo is outputting 'My Project' instead of 'My.Project'

```
- script: echo "projectKey2 is ${{replace(${{ variables.projectName }},' ','.')}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra brackets around `variables.projectName` that should not be there:

```yaml
- script: echo "projectKey2 is ${{ replace(variables.projectName,' ','.') }}"
```